# Net/HTTP in rails with request header and body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to call external API for my project and I have some troubles while using `Net::HTTP` in my rails `lib` . Here is my code

```
class ApiCall
 def self.do_api_request(api_token, body)
    require 'net/http'
    require 'uri'
    uri = URI.parse('https://sample.com')
    header = {'Token' => api_token, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == "https")
    request.body = body
    http.request(request)
 end
end
```

This is how I use it (assume I knew the `api_token` and `body`):

`body = {'id' => 2, 'age'=> 23};`

```
ApiCall.do_api_request(api_token, body)
```

This way, it throws an error back:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for Hash

Then after check online, seems like the body is hash instead of string, so I did this 
`body = URI.encode_www_form(body)` and after rerun, it gives me :

> 400 bad request

I have no ideas how to put both header and body into a rails `Net::HTTP` method

**Solution:**

I know where the problem is. `request body` supposed to be `string`
so `body = "{'id' : 2, 'age' : 23}"` , I used `body.to_json`

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) for calling an api. This is real simple to use. Following are the examples-

```
HTTParty.get("https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/"+@store.store_hash+"/v3/catalog/categories", :headers => @your_header_data)
```

This will return the response. Also for post request,

```
HTTParty.post("https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/"+@store.store_hash+"/v3/catalog/products", :headers => @auth, :body => product_json)
```

So you can pass body to in body param here.